# How to change label size in lightningchart

Tags: lightningchart

How do we change label font size and color in Lightning chart
enter image description here

I add the label using code like below

```
 return builder
        .addRow(name)
        .addRow(yValue.toFixed(2))
        .addRow(timedata[xValue.toFixed(0)])
```

Also is it possible to seperately change color and size for only `.addRow(yValue.toFixed(2))` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AutoCursor result table font size / text color can be changed like this

```
chart.setAutoCursor((autoCursor) => autoCursor
   .setResultTable((resultTable) => resultTable
      .setFont((font) => font.setSize(12))
      .setTextFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA( 255, 0, 0 ) }))
   )
)
```

[AutoCursorXY API](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/interfaces/autocursorxy.html)

[ResultTable API](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v2.2.0/interfaces/resulttable.html)